# tf on electric + maverick + Beagleboard

Tags: ros, beagleboard, ros-electric, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am trying to get my custom robot to run from a beagleboard. I have Ubuntu 10.10 running on it and installed the ROS electric base variant. I have tried to install the full variant, but I get the following message:

E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-desktop-full

I require the tf package for my robot and have tried to install it using the following command in terminal:

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-tf

which could also not be found...

I have since installed everything that I could using this command:

$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-*

But I still dont have the tf package...

Can anybody give me instructions on how to get the tf package on my beagleboard...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11469/tf-on-electric-+-maverick-+-beagleboard/) by [gertr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1098/gertr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you are on the Beagleboard, you will need Armel packages, not the standard i386 or x86-64 packages. While Willow Garage has started to build Armel .debs, most ROS stacks are not currently building for Armel. See the [electric build status](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html) for details. You want the maverick-armel column and anything not in white will not have a .deb in the repository. Note that as of right now, geometry is not successfully built for armel.

You can try to install the `geometry` stack from source (using either `rosinstall` or just checking the stack out onto your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`), but since it's not building as a .deb, I don't expect it to build without patching on your Beagleboard. You may be able to build just `tf` (`rosmake --rosdep-install tf`) after checking out the `geometry` stack and, if `tf` and it's dependencies don't fail, you'll be able to get up and running.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [tf package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) is in the geometry stack. Thus, it is installed if you have the debian package ros-electric-geometry installed. If that can't be installed then maybe there is no ROS apt-repository in your sources.list?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1